# Is it possible to make the approval form directly accessible on sharepoint Or by creating a one click direct link to the form on email

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer

[image: sharepoint]

Is there any way I can approve a list item directly instead of  using the (Title) as a link to the approval form....Like a single click?
[image]
Or is it possible to access the approval form directly  by creating a link in the email.
Iam using sharepoint designer

Answer (score 0):

1.In the user profile, fill in the "Work email" property of the user who will handle the approval task.

2.When you send approval task to the user, he will receive an email as following picture shows.
[image]

Comment: This is easier when you are using content approval, how about when you are not using content approval